# Нужна ли запятая перед единичным "или"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы

«Витамин С, витамин солнца, или аскорбиновая кислота — одно из незаменимых веществ для организма человека, мощный антиоксидант, играющий важную роль в регуляции окислительно-восстановительных процессов.»

Нужна ли запятая перед "или"? По правилам вроде нет, но если запятую убрать, то будет значение перечисления разных веществ.

Answer (score 1):

**Витамин С,  или аскорбиновая кислота,  — одно из незаменимых веществ для организма человека, мощный антиоксидант, играющий важную роль в регуляции окислительно-восстановительных процессов.**

Союз ИЛИ здесь — **пояснительный** (а не разделительный), поэтому запятая нужна. Это два разных названия одного вещества.

Как уже говорилось, **это не витамин солнца** (витамином солнца называют витамин Д). http://fb.ru/article/335115/kakoy-vitamin-daet-solntse-vitamin-vyirabatyivayuschiysya-na-solntse

Answer (score 0):

Запятая **ставится**, если союз **или** присоединяет пояснительную конструкцию, обозначающую одно и то же понятие другими словами:

http://russkiiyazyk.ru/punktuatsiya/kogda-pered-soyuzom-ili-stavitsya-zapyataya.html

Answer (score 0):

Витамином солнца называют обычно витамин D. Думаю, это название не подходит для витамина C. Но если нас интересует только грамматика и пунктуация, то давайте рассуждать дальше.

> Витамин С, витамин солнца, или аскорбиновая кислота - одно из незаменимых веществ для организма человека, мощный антиоксидант, играющий важную роль в регуляции окислительно-восстановительных процессов.

Предложение составлено не очень удачно. Есть два пояснения : "витамин солнца" и "аскорбиновая кислота", причем "поэтическое" пояснение стоит между основным названием и "техническим" пояснением , а это не очень хорошо. К тому же первое  пояснение вводится без союза, а второе — с союзом *или*. Если ничего не изменять, то я бы расставил знаки препинания так:

**Витамин С, витамин солнца или аскорбиновая кислота, — одно из незаменимых веществ для организма...**

При такой расстановке получается, что *или* — сочинительный союз внутри пояснения, а все пояснение целиком выделено запятыми.

А если изменять предложение, то вот мой вариант:

**Витамин С, или аскорбиновая кислота, называемый также витамином солнца, — одно из незаменимых веществ для организма...**